# Why i am not able to transmit messages through UART using Interrupts in STM32?

Tags: interrupt, stm32f7

```
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
{

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,"1 \r\n", 5,10);
    flag=1;
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0);
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++);

    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_13);
}
```

I am trying to display a message in serial window through UART, the above code  is working in main loop but does not working inside interrupt.

I am getting undefined reference to `HAL_UART_Trasmit` error.

Comment: Have you included the header file where the function `HAL_UART_Trasmit` is declared ? What is the UART configuration ? Is the interrupt active on Tx also ?

Comment: interrupt activates on push button, UART just to display message 1 in serial window with speed 115200, UART is initialized before calling

Comment: What about the header file for `HAL_UART_Trasmit` function ? Is that included ? Are the HAL Files included in your build ?

Comment: It should be "Transmit" instead of "Trasmit"

Comment: HAL header files are included

Comment: "Transmit"  done, still was not getting output

Comment: You can use a debugger and check if `HAL_UART_Transmit` returns `HAL_OK`. Could you share the UART configuration ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it fail to compile? Does it block? Does it crash? Does it continue without transmitting anything?

Comment: fails to compile